# How do I check if an input is a number and if it is if it is between 0 and 100?

Tags: c++

I need to test if the input is a number and if so if it is between 0 and 100. If it is not then it should say LOL NOOB.

I tried making a variable that has a list and it would see if the number is in the list and if it doesn't fit in the list it says NAN

```
while (title == 1) {
    ++level;

    system("cls");
    //variables
    char p;
    int secret, guess;
    float NumberDetection;
    NumberDetection = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100;

    // color
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 4);

    //the number that you guess!
    srand(time(NULL));
    secret = rand() % 100 - 0;


    cout << "  The Legit Guessing Game!" << endl << "   The Dankest of its kind!" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 6);
    cout << "Welcome my name is Luffy Computron. your currant level is " << level << endl;
    cout << " I will randomly pick a number between 0 and 100" << endl;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 22);
    cout << "Take a guess" << endl;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 2);
    cout << "Guess:";
    cin >> guess;
    if (guess == NumberDetection) {
        while (guess != secret) {
            if (guess > secret) {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 6);
                cout << "Too large. Try again." << endl;
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 2);
            }
            if (guess < secret) {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 6);
                cout << "Too small. Try again." << endl;
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 2);
            }
            cout << "Guess:";
            cin >> guess;
        }

        if (guess == secret) {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 6);
            cout << "Congradulations! The number was " << secret << endl;
            if (level == 1) {
                cout << "you are now an untrained aprentice of the computron team, ";
                cout << "to become an aprentice play 3 more times!";

            }
            else if (level == 2) {
                cout << "you are now an untrained aprentice of the computron team ";
                cout << "to become an aprentice play 2 more times!";

            }
            else if (level == 3) {
                cout << "you are now an untrained aprentice of the computron team ";
                cout << "to become an aprentice play 1 more times!";

            }
            else if (level == 4) {
                cout << "Congradulations you Leveled up to an aprentice of the computron team! ";
                cout << "Only 5 games left to level up to Journeyman!";

            }
            else if (level == 9) {
                cout << "Wow you are level 9!! that means you are a Journeyman! Congradulations!" << endl << "You have reached the top rank for now... But there is more to come!";

            }
            else
                cout << "you have passed my expectations! Con-drag-ulations!";
            cout << " Do you want to play again and better your guessing skills? " << endl;
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 2);
            cout << "[Y] Yes";
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 4);
            cout << "[N] No" << endl;
            cin >> p;

            if (p == 'N' || p == 'n') {
                title = 0;
            }

            else if (p == 'y' || p == 'Y') {
                title = 1;
            }
        }
        Sleep(30);
        while (title == 0) {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 4);
            cout << "/";
            Sleep(10);
            system("cls");
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 6);
            cout << "|";
            Sleep(10);
            system("cls");
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 14);
            cout << "\\";
            Sleep(10);
            system("cls");
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 10);
            cout << "--";
                            Sleep(10);
            system("cls");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else { 
    cout << "THATS NOT A NUMBER !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
    Sleep(10000);

    return 0;


    }
}
```

expected results are that it says not a number and then closes. But instead it  spams "TOO small try again".

Comment: `NumberDetection` is a single number - do you know which one?

Comment: Also what do you think `cin >> guess;` does when you enter something that is not an integer?

Comment: I didn't think about that Thank you!

Comment: `NumberDetection = 0, 1, 2, 3...` I can pretty much guarantee that this doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `secret = rand() % 100 - 0;`  you can remove the -0 part.

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` you should get this out of the loop. Call it 1 time at the beginning of `main`.

Comment: As for `srand`/`rand` see [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful). Consider [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) instead.

Comment: Specifically [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Comment: awesome thank you all!

Comment: @user11302233 Can you please concentrate to ask about your main issue and narrow down your code to a [mcve] that exactly reproduces the problem you're asking for. Notice that this is  a minimum effort required here.

Comment: Okay, sorry I will make sure to not show as much code next time!

Answer (score 1):

use the conditional statements when getting input from user

```
 int i;
 cout<<"Enter Value";
 if(cin>>i)
 {
     cout<<"value is Integer";
     if(i>=0 && i<=100)
     cout<<"value is between 0 and 100";
 }
```

Comment: For completeness you should tack on an `else` case that shows how to clean up `cin` if there is an error.